# With Arduino Mini Pro, can only upload once

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

When first talking to Mini Pro everything works. First sketch uploads and runs. BUT subsequent upload attempts error out.

Have tried on two different Mini Pros. Same results.

Running on Ubuntu. Port `/dev/ttyUSB0` OK - seen and permissions. Am using [this connector](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-PL2303-cable-PL2303HX-USB-to-TTL-Cable-module-4p-4-pin-RS232-Converter-Brush/32615917201.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.Ggf2Q4) and using [this board](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-20pcs-lot-STM8S103F3P6-system-board-STM8S-STM8-development-board-minimum-core-board/32276994863.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.k4ML8l).

Error message:

```
Arduino: 1.6.12 (Linux), Board: "Arduino Pro or Pro Mini, ATmega328 (5V, 16 MHz)"

Sketch uses 444 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30,720 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
/data/arduino/arduino-1.6.12/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/data/arduino/arduino-1.6.12/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -P/dev/ttyUSB0 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:/tmp/arduino_build_876010/pin-blink.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Sep 12 2016 at 15:21:49
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/data/arduino/arduino-1.6.12/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/maco/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyUSB0
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others suggested, there's a funky timing issue to make it work.

For my antique PC under Windows, I press reset, the Upload, count to six, and release reset. About 30% of the time this works.